# Having issues saving data to firebase db in nativescript application

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nativescript

Mega thanks in advance for your help.

I am using the nativescript firebase plugin by Eddy. I Can register users and login but i want to make user update profile. I followed the documentation on the plugin and the data actually logs a response key form the firerbase but whtn i login to firebase i do not see the data their. it still says null.

My code:

```
var observableModule = require("data/observable");
var applicationSettings = require("application-settings"); 
var firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");



function profilePageViewModel () {

firebase.init({
    url: 'https://freshersmeal-1e29e.firebaseio.com/'

  }).then(
      function (instance) {
        console.log("firebase.init done");
      },
      function (error) {
        console.log("firebase.init error: " + error);
      }
  );

//this function below is responsible for saving the d data
viewModel.saveProfile = function () {

    firebase.push(
          '/users',
        {
            'address': '12, loadster street.',
            'department': 'Comp',
            'level': 100
          }
        ).then(
          function (result) {
            console.log("created key: " + result.key);
          }
        );

}

return viewModel;

}

module.exports = profilePageViewModel;
```

What i want is to have like a users child node and all the users data save to it.

I have read lots of tutorials but can't see to find any of them facing this issue. What am i missing please?

Comment: Are you certain your users have permission to write the data?

Comment: Yes, very sure, i get a response key returned from firebase after each successful write but when, i check the firebase console. it still says my db is null.

Comment: Hmmm.... not sure what that could be. Any chance you could set up a jsbin that reproduces it, so that I can have a look?

Comment: Don't think it would be possible because I am using it on the web. I am using it in a cross platform framework for mobile apps; nativescript. Thank you.

Comment: Ah right, I had seen that but forgot. Hmm... I'll ponder a bit more, but maybe someone else has an idea already.

Comment: Okay. I too will ponder more on it and try it at a later time. Gracias Frank

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you already solved this issue, but I had the same one and found a solution.
Instead of only having `firebase.push()` you should write `return firebase.push()`